# How can I provide "driver.find_element" for the button in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium and Python, writing my first code to log in to a specified website and got stuck with the button part, not sure how to give an XPath to the below button code.

```
<button class="js-tfaLoginButton Button Button--pill Button--action Loadable u-marginBottomStandard u-size1of2 u-cursorPointer u-outlineNone" type="submit" data-qa="submit_login">
    Sign In
</button>
```

Tried out the below XPath but doesn't work:

```
/button[@class="js-tfaLoginButton Button Button--pill Button--action Loadable u-marginBottomStandard u-size1of2 u-cursorPointer u-outlineNone"]@class
```

Or is there any other method instead of XPath?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath is:

```
//button[@class="js-tfaLoginButton Button Button--pill Button--action Loadable u-marginBottomStandard u-size1of2 u-cursorPointer u-outlineNone"]
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I have the following code,    <div class="UserIcon UserIcon--default u-flex u-flexAlignItemsCenter u-flexJustifyCenter u-zeta u-fontWeightBold u-width1Up u-height1Up">N</div> .   Even for this i need to use xpath or class ?

Comment: You, for locating any element on the page you need to use: id, class, XPath, CSS Selector and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We have the following ways to identify the element in the browser

```
ID = "id"
XPATH = "xpath"
LINK_TEXT = "link text"
PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
NAME = "name"
TAG_NAME = "tag name"
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

Out of the above ways to locate element. We can use tagname or value(text) present inside the tag, like this:

XPATH:

`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Sign In"]')`

or

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Sign In"]')`

TAG_NAME:

`driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, '//button')`