# Python Selenium Not Able to Grab XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently the login for [this site](https://www.stellarmls.com/) changed and no longer recognizes my Python bot. Specifically, the issue appears to be occurring on the login page where it is unable to select the username input textbox. The id for it is 'loginId' and the correct XPATH appears to be `"//*[@name='loginId']"`

The line I am attempting to use (that used to work) is:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@name='loginId']"))).send_keys(username)
```

The error message I am receiving clearly states it is not finding the element and is timing out:

```
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Python3.9\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried all of the suggested names/paths/ids found in both Katalon Recorder and Selenium IDE. This does not appear to be an iFrame. Not sure what is going on.

Any thoughts or input would be helpful here. Link is provided up above if you can check it out that would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Supplemental code [EDIT 07/05/2022]:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\Splitt\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get("https://www.stellarmls.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-form-row"]/form/div/div[3]/div/a'))).click()

driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginId").send_keys('username')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your code and instead plugged in your site to a Selenium script I had and it worked without issue:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginId").send_keys(username)
```

It essentially does the same thing without the explicit wait. The fact that it was missing didn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that didn't seem to do it. I get the error: `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="loginId"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66)`

Comment: Are you using this exact code? Why is the error mentioning a css selector?

Comment: Yep, I used the exact code. In addition to some additional ones suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580657/11144854. I think that is just calling out the method that was selected using the `By.`

Comment: I just tried this out again and in my case there was no issue sending a string to the input. Since the page has an input with the attribute "name" which equals to loginId, there is no logical reason as to why Selenium wouldn't be able to find the input. Are you using some kind of custom setup? What is the value you are passing in to the input? Try using `By.ID` instead.

Comment: Added code above. See Supplemental code [EDIT 07/05/2022]

Comment: I don't know how to explain this but apparently the login page needed to be launched using the below url and not starting with the short url to the main page: https://stellarmls-login.sso.remine.com/login?state=hKFo2SBIcUpkWWdBalVSa3FRZzlfRTRQMVdVTHA3Umxia0MzZqFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgbGRSOUw0Mm9ZQkVkV28tdkR1dUdWVHhBTW1WZVdFN0ujY2lk2SA0T2l1NWpQbG5SS252TkVvb3JIQzlIUnRkbHpnUXNDMQ&client=4Oiu5jPlnRKnvNEoorHC9HRtdlzgQsC1&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsvc.moxiworks.com%2Fservice%2Fv1%2Fauth%2Fsessions%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email#signin

Comment: Hmm that is strange considering that the elements of the page are the same